# xml ajax get nested items

Tags: xml, ajax

Hello i am having trouble getting an nested element in xml working with ajax, i have this as an xml file (this is an example)

```
<root>
     <element1>
          <child1></child1>
          <child2></child2>
     </element1>
     <element2>
          <child1></child1>
          <child2></child2>
     </element2>
</root>
```

and below is the ajax code i am using that is used to get what i am looking for

```
data.getElementsByTagName('child1')
```

Now my question is how do i get it to only show the child1 inside element1?

Answer (score 0):

i got the problem i edited it as below

```
data.getElementsByTagName('child1') [0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Changing the [0] selects the different one.